# Is there a NavBar element with material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been working on this react app and we're shifting from react-strap to material UI. Material UI has appbar and drawer components but not a navbar, is there a simpler way to go about converting a react-strap navbar to a material UI one?

Comment: Please add relevant tags. Is it react.js?

Comment: please have a look at [navtab](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/#nav-tabs), it could help you